# Why is ServiceStack returning POCO objects slower than .NET Remoting returning a DataSet?

Tags: servicestack

I'm returning a DataTable with 6100 rows and 156 columns from a service.

```
When returning it over .NET remoting it takes 1800 ms.
When returning it over .NET remoting with optimized DataSet serialization, it takes 1350 ms.

When just downloading a List<T> from ServiceStack (selfhosted) like this:
webClient.DownloadData("http://localhost:1337/hello/xx"); it takes 1400 ms

when returning the same list as really typed list - List<T>
var restClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:1337/hello");
all = restClient.Get<HelloResponse>("/xx"); it takes 2100 ms
```

To me it seems like returning a list of POCO objects from ServiceStack service is slower than .NET Remoting returning a typed DataSet.

T in this case looks like this (it has quite a lot of nullable properties and tolal of 156 properties):

```
public partial class Nmbr
{       
    public Int32 NmbrID {get;set;}
    public Int32 NmbrNmBaID {get;set;}
    public Int32 NmbrNmStID {get;set;}
    public Int32 NmbrNmInID {get;set;}
    public String NmbrDesc {get;set;}
    public Int32? SestID {get;set;}
    public Int32? SestProjID {get;set;}
```

....
....

What am'I doing wrong?
Why returning List is slower than returning a DataSet?
All methods share the same mechanism to get data from a DB... to me it seems like deserialization in ServiceStack is slow. Downloading data using  webClient.DownloadData is faster than default DataSet serialization, but converting it to typed List adds additional 700ms according to my measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see or run your code to compare and verify where the performance is being spent I'd suggest that using self-describing formats like JSON is not optimal when returning a typed POCO full of integers since the overhead of each type is repeated for every row which when you have mostly numbers means that most of the payload is serializing/deserializing the schema instead of the data, e.g:

```
 [{"NumbrId":0,"NmbrNmBaID":0,"NmbrNmStID":0,...,etc},...]
```

You should also be looking and comparing of the size of the serialized data to see how much of the payload overhead is in the schema vs the raw data.

Also to be clear when you're calling:

```
webClient.DownloadData("http://localhost:1337/hello/xx");
```

You're just downloading the raw serialized data which is always going to be faster than having it deserialized into the typed POCOs. You can also download the raw data using [ServiceStack's .NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) with:

```
var bytes = restClient.Get<byte[]>("http://localhost:1337/hello/xx");
```

So you're able to compare the performance of downloading content from ServiceClient vs WebClient.

#### Consider using optimal Data Formats

For large Tabular/numerical datasets like this consider using a more optimal binary format with ServiceStack like [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format) or [Message Pack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MessagePack-Format) which would benefit greatly since they wouldn't need to repeat the schema in every row. For a text-based format, even CSV would be a better fit for transferring tabular data for the same reasons.

You can also improve the performance for ServiceStack's JSON Serializer on DataSets like this by using [Custom Serialization with Structs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#custom-serialization), which would also save the overhead of the repeating schema.

Comment: restClient.Get<byte[]> takes 1250 ms.  Using MsgPackServiceClient getting typed POCOs it takes 1350ms.  So it is the same as optimized DataSet serialization.  Thanks for your fast answer.

Comment: @pavsej np glad it helped - don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to mark the question off as complete.

Comment: Sorry, I was to quick. A detail look revealed that MessagePack fails to serialize objects with more than 127 properties. Exception beeing "'count' is negative" at MsgPack.Packer.PackArrayHeaderCore(.... I'll evaluate other options

Comment: I got it running with Protocol Buffers, now I'm getting data in less than  850ms. With JSON it was 2100ms. I measured DB access and it takes 650ms to read data from my database. So in my particular case I went from 1450ms to 200ms - data serialization got more than 7 times quicker!